# I Am Working On Flutter App And Facing Some Issue Regarding Entity To Model Conversion

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, clean-architecture, design-principles

I Am Working On Flutter App And Facing Some Issue Regarding Entity To Model Conversion

This is my Parent Partner class

```
  final int? id;
  final String? displayName;
  

  Partner(
      {this.id,
      required this.displayN``your text``ame,
      });
}
```

This my child PartnerModel class

```
  PartnerModel.search({super.id, super.displayName}) : super.search();

  PartnerModel(
      {super.id,
      super.displayName,
      });
```

And this is my PurchaseOrder class

```
  final DateTime? dateOrder;
  final DateTime? createDate;
  final String? origin;
  final Partner? vendor;


  const PurchaseOrder(
      {
      required this.dateOrder,
      this.createDate,
      this.origin
      required super.assignedUser,
      required this.vendor,
      });
}
```

And this is my PurchaseOrderModel class

```
  const PurchaseOrderModel(
      {
      required super.dateOrder,
      required super.createDate,
      required super.origin,
      required super.vendor,
      super.linePurchaseOrder})
      : super();
```

In PurchaseOrder class i created a vendor entity with Partner Type In PuchaseOrderModel
vendor type should remain Partner or change to PartnerModel because i am facing some issues.
I have created custom entity type Partner and i am facing issue in PurchaseOrderModel because it inherits from PurchaseOrder which has Partner Type vendor but in POModel it expects PartnerModel.
What is the best solution.